# Composing HTTP POST Request on iOS When No API Available?

Tags: asp.net, ios, http, post, http-post

I'm working on an iOS app that will take an ISBN from a book and look it up on a website specific to school work for my kids. The website doesn't have an API that I can find, so I'm trying to submit an HTTP POST request to their .aspx form and get a response back that can then be stripped and stored in an iOS table view.

I have the UIwebview setup and have tried composing various POST requests but I always get the default page back. I don't know enough about http requests, or aspx pages, to know if what I'm trying to do is even possible.

It also looks like it's setting a cookie the first time you visit based on your user type. I just select parent and then do an advanced search. I've looked at other iOS libraries to help implement the POST but I think I'm getting hung up on the basic formatting / is it even possible point right now.

The website is http://www.arbookfind.com/advanced.aspx

I've tried many methods to send my request - here's one example:

```
NSString *post = @"__LASTFOCUS:\r\n__EVENTTARGET:\r\n__EVENTARGUMENT:\r\nctl00$txtKeycode:\r\nKeyCodeSubmitField:\r\nctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$radlstFulltextSearchType:ALLWORDS\r\nctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtTitle:\r\nctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtAuthor:\r\nctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtISBN:1452102953\r\nctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lstQuizReleasedInLastHowManyDays:0\r\nctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lstQuizType:Any\r\nctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lstInterestLevel:Any\r\nctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtBLMin:\r\nctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtBLMax:\r\nctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lstTopics:0\r\nctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lstSubTopics:0\r\nctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lstFictionNonFiction:2\r\nctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lstLanguage:2\r\nctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lstSort:0\r\nctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnDoIt:Go";

 NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
 NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
```

I appreciate the help, pointers, feedback, etc.

Comment: Do you need to look it up on that website? Their are other sites that have free APIs to do this. One of them is: http://openlibrary.org/dev/docs/api/books. Normally, the method you are describing is not recommended because any time someone changes the webpage, your code will likely break.

Comment: Unfortunately I do need to look it up on that site because it's a proprietary testing system the school uses. My kids need their custom quiz number so they can take the appropriate test.  As a parent we also need to use this site to check the book "level" to make sure it's appropriate - that's why I'm trying to make a bar code scanner because manually typing book names is driving me nuts.

Comment: Have you ever used fiddler before? http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ It lets you inspect the commands you are sending to the server. It looks like their are some field differences from what you posted. Also, the page is using a view-source, where it stores and encrypts some values on the page and then sends them back. This is common for .asp pages and is difficult to simulate if it needs them. I would see if you can replicate the call without the viewstate objects first.

Comment: I had been using Chrome's developer tools to capture data and see what was going back and forth, but I just tried Fiddler. I copied and pasted the data straight out of the SyntaxView tab and my initial test worked for the first time. I still have to work through the cookie issue, but I'm further than I was. Thanks for the help!